# Cannot set-up Github server in the System configuration section of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, github-api

I get a `Can't create GH token - https://api.github.com/authorizations {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}` error

I am reading the **Learning Continuous Integration with Jenkins 2ed** by **Nikhil Pathania**

I have created global credentials with login and password and I have to generate a token out of it. Generating the Token gives the above error.